# Javascript suddenly can not read value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I'm in the process of writing a client side app that given the ingredients will give you cocktail recipe. When inputted, you click on a button will search the ingredients. If "all" is entered you will be redirected to page with all the recipes.

I had just started this so note the all feature is the only part I've done.
It was working fine. For practice I had it when you entered "all" it would redirect to facebook's url. Out of nowhere(with no new changes) it started throwing me an error, it wasn't reading the input, it was reading it as null.

The relevant HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="alcohol">
<h4 class="btn" type="submit" onclick="whole()"> Search</h4>
```

The JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('alcohol').value;

function whole() {
    if (input == "all") {
        window.location = "http://www.facebook.com";
    };
};
```

What's happening here? Why did it stop working?

Comment: Because the input value will be an empty string. Put input variable assignment inside the "whole" function.

Comment: something like the above, I think it is because you are not using "ready" or "load" events and then target the input

Comment: A ready or load event won't help. The value of input will not change once assigned.

Comment: hm yes, actually you are correct, 2 beers are enough for missing this apparently :D

Comment: An `<h4>` with `type="submit"`? Also, an `<h4>` with an `onclick` is not accessible to users who can't use a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: Putting the variable in the function did the trick, thanks very much :) also, about the <h4> with the submit, I havn't slept in a while and I do silly things without sleep.

Comment: @FiachOneill - Since it looks like you may be new here, if the answer below solves your problem, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This marks it as the "accepted" answer and also earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to see a greater context to know for sure, but it appears that you are probably getting the alcohol value too soon before it contains the latest value.

You can change to this to make the `whole()` function work with the current value of the alcohol field:

```
  function whole(){
    var input = document.getElementById('alcohol').value;
    if (input =="all"){
      window.location="http://www.facebook.com";
    };
  };
```

Remember that this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('alcohol').value;
```

gets the current value at the time that line of code is run.  Any future changes to that field will not affect the `input` variable.  That variable contains the value from a specific point in time only.  The easiest way to avoid issues like this is to just get the value right when you need it, not some time earlier.

Comment: Or `var input = document.getElementById('alcohol');` to keep a reference to the element, then `input.value` to get its current value. (Assuming the JS is run after the elements are parsed.)

Comment: jfriend00 is correct, its trying to read the value when the script is loaded, and thats proberly before the html exist.